# ajax code error in aspx page

Tags: asp.net-ajax

where do i put the code in aspx page if i want to display hover menu,,if i put anywhere in aspx page its throwing errors

the code is

```
   <ajaxToolkit:HoverMenuExtender ID="hme2" runat="Server"
    TargetControlID="GridView1"
    PopupControlID="PopupMenu"
    HoverCssClass="popupHover"
    PopupPosition="Left"
    OffsetX="0"
    OffsetY="0"
    PopDelay="50" />
```

errors like unrecoganized tag filter 'ajaxToolkit' ,,,this name contain upper case character which is not allowed,,like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a ScriptManager on the page with the registered assembly?

Comment: No i dont have,,how to put that

Comment: i put like this then also 
<%@ Register assembly="System.Web.Ajax" namespace="System.Web.UI" tagprefix="asp" %>

some where in code this also
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                        </asp:ScriptManager>,,but same error getting

Comment: It's been awhile since I have wrote ASP.NET, but I believe you are now using the wrong tag prefix; change it to be "ajaxToolkit"